# amcharts4 dynamic location marker

Tags: javascript, dictionary, dynamic, amcharts, amcharts4

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/

I need to add a location marker when I click a button. I tried `imageSeries.data.push`, `addData`, `init` and other methods but when I move the chart (`mappositionchanged`) is triggered location updates.
I need to make it work automatically without moving or zooming the chart.

I am using amcharts version 4.

```js
function test() {
    imageSeries.addData({
        "zoomLevel": 5,
        "scale": 0.5,
        "title": "Pretoria",
        "latitude": -25.7463,
        "longitude": 28.1876
    });
    alert(imageSeries.data);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="test();">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate this behavior where adding data dynamically to a `MapImageSeries` via its [`addData` method](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimageseries/#addData_method) requires refreshing the chart (for what it's worth, user [posted the same issue to our GitHub](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1067) and solved it there.). `imageSeries.addData(...)` should work just fine.

Setup code:

```js
// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

// Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

// Create image series
var imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());

// Create a circle image in image series template so it gets replicated to all new images
var imageSeriesTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
var circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
circle.radius = 4;
circle.fill = am4core.color("#B27799");
circle.stroke = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");
circle.strokeWidth = 2;
circle.nonScaling = true;
circle.tooltipText = "{title}";

// Set property fields
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
```

Test code (`addPlace` method):

```js
// Add data for the three cities

var data = [{
  "latitude": 48.856614,
  "longitude": 2.352222,
  "title": "Paris",
  zoomLevel: 1
}, {
  "latitude": 40.712775,
  "longitude": -74.005973,
  "title": "New York",
  zoomLevel: 2
}, {
  "latitude": 49.282729,
  "longitude": -123.120738,
  "title": "Vancouver",
  zoomLevel: 4
}];

const dataIterator = data[Symbol.iterator]();

function addPlace() {
  var item = dataIterator.next();
  if ( !item.done) {
    imageSeries.addData(item.value);
  }
}
```

Here's a quick demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c5a5803d81b9517a8fd37d4e2c6541ed

The "Add Marker" button adds a marker each time (up to 3 times since there's only 3 items in the array) without having to refresh the chart (via `invalidate` or whatever).

Comment: Here `data `don't have `id`. Then one can get clicked object using `getPolygonById` to zoom it. What is the ulternate here for `getPolygonById`